# If domain name points to an IP, then cname to that domain will also point to that IP?

Tags: dns, ip, cname

Let's suppose I am having a domain `example.com` and it point to an IP `111.11.11.1`.
In case I cname a new domain `example2.com` to `example.com`.

Will it also points to `111.11.11.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-cname-record/,

> All CNAME records must point to a domain, never to an IP address. Imagine a scavenger hunt where each clue points to another clue, and the final clue points to the treasure. A domain with a CNAME record is like a clue that can point you to another clue (another domain with a CNAME record) or to the treasure (a domain with an A record).

So it will not point directly, put it will point to the domain that points to the IP

Answer (score 0):

CNAME is an alias: it points to another domain name and will resolve the alias target IP, but you will never see in plain text that `example2.com` points to `111.11.11.1`.
You can check for example [rfc1034](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034) for more informations:

```
For example, suppose a name server was processing a query with for USC-
ISIC.ARPA, asking for type A information, and had the following resource
records:

USC-ISIC.ARPA   IN      CNAME   C.ISI.EDU

C.ISI.EDU       IN      A       10.0.0.52

Both of these RRs would be returned in the response to the type A query,
while a type CNAME or * query should return just the CNAME.
```